# Keep DROP_DOWN ToolItem highlighted while menu is shown

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I have a `ToolItem` as `SWT.DROP_DOWN`, and a `selectionListener` to popup a `Menu` with a few `menuItem`.

The ToolItem is highlighted when mouseover, and on click the submenu appears. However, the ToolItem is no longer highlighted. Is there any way to keep it highlighted until I select one of the menu items (or click from somewhere else to close)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SWT uses the native widgets of the platform it runs on. Hence, the highlighting behavior is entirely up to the platforms implementation.

I fear there is no way to highlight the tool button while the drop-down menu is shown.

Comment: I use CHECK instead and fake it as DROP_DOWN, then i can do a hack to make it work as expected

Answer (score 0):

I use `CHECK` instead of `DROP_DOWN`, and add `MenuListener` to the menu and override `menuHidden()` to deselect the ToolItem. By doing this, ToolItem is selected until the Menu disappears.

To make the ToolItem looks like a dropdown, I can draw the arrow to the item.